# Mongoose won't update a document

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm encountering few problems when dealing with mongoose.

I wrote the following snippet of code:

```
if (!usr.settings) usr.settings = {};
async.forEach(Object.keys(params), function (item, nextitem){
    usr.settings[item] = params[item];
    nextitem();
}, function (err) {
    if (err) return callback(err);
    usr.save(function(err) {
        if (err) return callback(err);
        return callback();
    });
});
```

When I first use it, it works just fine, it creates all the items in the document perfectly, but when I use it the 2nd time (lets say I want to update those items) it doesn't change their values nor gives me any error.
The data stays just the same.

I tried to debug it.

```
if (!usr.settings) usr.settings = {};
async.forEach(Object.keys(params), function (item, nextitem){
    usr.settings[item] = params[item];
    nextitem();
}, function (err) {
    if (err) return callback(err);
    usr.save(function(err) {
        console.log(usr); <------------------- [At this point it shows the updated data but for some reason it doesnt save it to the db]
        if (err) return callback(err);
        return callback();
    });
});
```

Any idea why it could happen? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After messing with it, found the solution.

lets say you are using the following schema:

```
user_schema = {
    settings = Object
}
```

you won't be able to set setting., therefore the following code:

```
usr.settings.something = 123;
usr.save(function(err) {
    if (err) return callback(err);
    return callback();
});
```

will do nothing and still will not result in an error.
If you want to fix the issue, apply this fix to the schema:

```
user_schema = {
    settings = {
        something : Number
        something_else: Object
    }
}
```

now you will be able to set `something` with a value :)

I wish it would helpful to someone